# Where to decide what item should be evicted from cache?

Tags: c#, caching

When size of the cache reaches the capacity, should the function, that decides what should be evicted, be located in cache class or it should be passed as argument to the cache class in it's initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. If you apply the single responsibility principle , it makes sense to inject the eviction logic in. So the cache object is responsible for caching and the injected eviction function/class is responsible for the eviction logic. This way you can reuse your cache with multiple eviction strategies.